# How to prevent objects inside an SVG drawing to be clipped at the bounds of the SVG element in chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, svg

I'm using SVG to draw an interactive diagram which can change a lot with user interaction. More precisely, is can expand in any direction (including negative coordinates) as the user adds entities.

I would like to think about my SVG object like an infinite plan that can contain objects, that would be drawn no matter where they are. And I use the position and the transform of this object to allow the user to zoom and move the part that's currently visible on the screen.
[image]
The problem is that with a naïve implementation I get this:
[image]

I made a minimal [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MWqCW/) to reproduce the issue, with this SVG code

```
<svg>
    <rect x="-10" y="35" width="40" height="40"
    style="stroke: black; fill: none;"/>
    <!-- roof -->
    <polyline points="-10 35, 10 7.68, 30 35" 
    style="stroke:black; fill: none;"/>
    <!-- door -->
    <polyline points="10 75, 10 55, 20 55, 20 75"
    style="stroke:black; fill: none;"/>
</svg>
```

and this css code

```
svg {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    position: absolute; top: 30px; left: 30px;
}
```

I know that I could: dynamically change the viewBox of the SVG, and apply an offset to the svg element, but that would be quite a painful refactoring because it's an old code ported from VML and there is a lot of interaction that makes coordinates systems conversions. So I would like a solution that doesn't involve changing the coordinates systems.

***Edit***: I forgot to mention it in the first time, but `"overflow: visible"` doesn't produce the expected result: children are still clipped.

***Q: Is there a way to get the browser to draw outside the bounds of the SVG element ?***

Note: a chrome only solution would be OK for me, even if I prefer using a standard solution.

Answer (score 14):

The usual way would be to add [overflow](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/masking.html#OverflowAndClipProperties)="visible" to the svg element

Comment: Thanks, but `overflow: visible` doesn't work here (I forgot to mention it in the first time, so I edited the question to add this information)

Comment: Report it as a Chrome bug then.

Comment: Here it is https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=96163

Neither of the suggested workarounds (clip:auto or clip:rect(large negative, large positive, large positive, large negative)) appears to work.

Comment: this now works in chrome, firefox and ie: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MWqCW/6/)

Comment: colmanj's fiddle works for me in Firefox and Chrome, but apparently overflow="visible" still doesn't work [in Safari](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=96163#c18) (I can't verify this)

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work in Safari (16.5).